# How can I "fake" a file to a web service using Java WS/RS annotations?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs, jax-ws

I'm trying to post to a webservice.  I'm using an annotated interface and then a CXF jaxrs:client configured in Spring.  The service expects username, password and a file so this works:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
String uploadFile(
    @QueryParam("username") String username,
    @QueryParam("password") String password,
    @Multipart() File file
);
```

However sometimes I want to use the service but I don't have the file as a file on disk, only as a string, and I can't write a temporary file.  So I'm looking for annotations which will produce the same exact post but from a string.  This doesn't work:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
String uploadFile(
    @QueryParam("username") String username,
    @QueryParam("password") String password,
    @Multipart() String file
);
```

Is there a correct way I can do this with the annotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@Multipart File` feature is a convenience. You don't have to use it. You can operate at the next level down. For one thing, it probably works on in InputStream. See [the documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-multiparts.html), particularly under 'Uploading files with Client API'.

Comment: Using InputStream doesn't produce the same request.  It's missing the `Content-Disposition: form-data;name=file;filename=myfile.txt` in the payload.

Comment: So add it. The api is there.

Comment: Ah OK there is no way to do this with the annotations?

Comment: You could look into `@HttpHeader` I recommend the cxf user mailing list for help at this level of detail.